# How to find out which files currently in my iPod would be deleted or modified if I synchronize it?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, ipod, disk-space

The brief version of my question is pretty much what the title says:

> How can I safely determine which of the files currently in my iPod would be deleted or modified if I synchronized it in iTunes?

(The term "modified" is admittedly a bit fuzzy.  If more precision is needed, I'll define "modified" to mean that the old and new versions are not "equal", where files A and B are defined to be "equal" if `diff A B` produces no output to the terminal.)

(Of course, simply synchronizing the iPod and then "looking for what's missing or changed" is ***not*** an acceptable answer.  If you need more details, please read on.)

---

As I explained in [another post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/undeletable-videos-in-ipod), as part of a troubleshooting effort, I would like to enable synchronization for my iPod, in iTunes.

Unfortunately, I am almost certain that synchronizing this iPod with my current iTunes library would result in the modification or outright deletion of *many* files from my iPod.

The obvious solution of backing up the entire iPod, and restoring it later, is not an option, simply because at the moment I do not have a sufficiently convenient 150GB of disk space that I could use for this.  (In fact, the problem that motivates this post arose as I was trying to make some room in my hard drive.)

But I *may* have enough room to back up the subset of those files now in my iPod that *would be deleted or modified* upon synchronization.  Hence the question posed at the beginning of this post.

Comment: Why would any files be removed to begin with? iTunes shouldn't *remove* anything unless you've set the iPod to let iTunes manage the music/apps/photos/etc automatically.